# C++ Expected a ';' error in code

Tags: c++, winhttp, winhttprequest

I am really confused why i get the following error `expected';'` on `hSession` on line 13.  I am not missing any semi-colons so im confused as to what this error means on my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <WinHttp.h>

int main()
{

//  WinHTTP newHTTP("http://api/");

    //initialize http and return session handle
    HINTERNET hSession = WinHttpOpen(L"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36",
        WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_NO_PROXY, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0);

    //make the connection request
    //HINTERNET hRequest = WinHTTpOpenRequest(hConnect, L"GET", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0); // open request and return HINTERNET handle

    // WinHTTPSendRequests finallys makes the connection to url

    //
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try to remove `#include "stdafx.h"`

Comment: What compiler are you using? Is that the entire and only error message?

Comment: In my experience with that error, chances are `HINTERNET` isn't being recognized as a type.

Comment: @S.M. Visual studio requires that file to be loaded.i am using visual studio 2017's compiler, no other errors.

Comment: @chris do i need to perhaps include other dll or libraries ?

Comment: I don't know anything about winhttp.h in particular. Check whether any provided basic examples compile.

Comment: [Include windows.h](http://rextester.com/ZWIZX38913), it has nothing to do with what you wrote

Comment: @PasserBy, Odd that this header wouldn't include that if it's required.

Comment: @chris I only guessed, there was a huge amount of undefined identifiers. But yeah it is weird as hell

Comment: @PasserBy thanks alot! strange theres no mention of this in the winhttp documentation

Comment: I'm getting same error declaring "unsigned int" instead "HINTERNET". I'm including iostream and string also. Maybe a vscode issue?